# connect Logstash 1.5.0 with log4j of several servers

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to connect logstash (Version 1.5.0) to get logs of services (that run on apache-tomcat). These logs are log4j.

I use this config for logstash:

```
input { 
  log4j {
    mode => server
    host => localhost
    port => 4560
    type => "log4j"
  }
}...
```

and in my service' log4j.xml I've set my SocketAppender:

```
<appender name="OHADS" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender">
    <param name="port" value="4560" />
    <param name="remoteHost" value="localhost" />
</appender>
```

It works fine.

The questions:

1. I want logstash to collect logs **not from my 'localhost', but from other tomcats, from other machines, as well**. How can I do that? when I tried to put in the "host" (in logstash config) something other than localhost (or the IP of the local machine), i got error on startup:

> "Cannot assign requested address - bind - Cannot assign requested
>   address".

2. How can I connect it to *several* IPs simultanously?

any ideas?

Comment: Since you're running `mode => server`, `host` actually specifies the host/IP to *listen* on, in which case the default `0.0.0.0` should be fine.

Comment: thanks. why it behaves differently than if the port is "localhost"? and what should be set in the log4j.properties?

Comment: @rutter please write it as an answer and I will accept it.