# logstash: in log4j-input, the "path" is not correct

Tags: logstash

In my config file, I use

```
input { log4j {} }
```

and:

```
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

I've [attached my log4j to logstash using SocketListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624467/connect-logstash-1-5-0-with-log4j-of-several-servers). When my app prints something to the log, I see in logstash:

```
{
"message" => "<the message>",
"@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2015-06-05T20:28:23.312Z",
"type" => "log4j",
"host" => "127.0.0.1:52083",
"path" => "com.ohadr.logs_provider.MyServlet",
"priority" => "INFO",
"logger_name" => "com.ohadr.logs_provider.MyServlet",
"thread" => "http-apr-8080-exec-3",
"class" => "?",
"file" => "?:?",
"method" => "?",
}
```

the issue is that the **"path"** field is wrong: AFAI understand, it should be **the path of the log file**; instead, I get the same value as "logger_name".

I have several apps on my tomcat that I want to collect the logs from. I need "path" to be the path-of-file (including the file-name), so I can distinguish between logs from different apps (each app logs to a different file).

How can it be done?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `log4j` input is a listener on a TCP socket. There is no file path.

To solve your challenge, you can either configure multiple TCP ports, so every application logs to a different TCP port or you could use GELF. GELF is an UDP-based protocol, but you need additional jars. logstash supports also GELF as native input. You can specify in many GELF appenders static fields, so you can distinguish on application level, which application is currently logging.

You can find [here](https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf#log4j-gelf-configuration) an example:

```
<appender name="gelf" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j.GelfLogAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="Host" value="udp:localhost" />
    <param name="Port" value="12201" />
    <param name="Version" value="1.1" />
    <param name="Facility" value="java-test" />
    <param name="ExtractStackTrace" value="true" />
    <param name="FilterStackTrace" value="true" />
    <param name="MdcProfiling" value="true" />
    <param name="TimestampPattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSS" />
    <param name="MaximumMessageSize" value="8192" />

    <!-- This are static fields -->
    <param name="AdditionalFields" value="fieldName1=fieldValue1,fieldName2=fieldValue2" />

    <!-- This are fields using MDC -->
    <param name="MdcFields" value="mdcField1,mdcField2" />
    <param name="DynamicMdcFields" value="mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields" />
    <param name="IncludeFullMdc" value="true" />
</appender>
```

HTH, Mark

Comment: thanks! to make this answer "complete", you may add the logstash configuration of "gelf" input, but I assume I can read about it myself :-) and I believe that I will have to use "grok" in order to parse the log-line by myself (log4j input does it automatically...) Am I right? can you share a good example of this grok? thanks again!

Comment: No, not at all. GELF is a structured log format, so you'll get the message in the message field, time in the timestamp field and so on. The logstash GELF input config looks like: `input { gelf{} }`

Comment: it works like a charm on my Tomcat. I can know which log line comes from which service, thanks to the "static variables"! do you have any idea how this solution can work with hadoop tasks? i have hadoop jobs, each one creates several tasks, and each task has it log file. Can gelf fit this use case?

Comment: I created a sample on hadoop logstash logging. Check out my post: http://www.paluch.biz/blog/95-logging-hadoop-messages-into-logstash-using-logstash-gelf.html, hope this helps

Comment: I saw this blog while ago, and I was not sure whether it fits my needs; I understood that it collects hadoop-deamons logs, and not the tasks-logs. Am I right?